# Pass request model inside of a parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a model that I send to an API inside on a parameter but get an error stating:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AVAFModel'.

```
submitAvafDetails(): Observable<any> {
  this.avafBcmsVo = 'avafVO:{' + this.prepareAvafSubmitData() +'}';
  return this.httpService.processData('POST', CONSTANTS.API_URL + 'testService.exp', this.avafBcmsVo);
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```js
this.avafBcmsVo = 'avafVO:{' + this.prepareAvafSubmitData() +'}';
```

Here is my model:

```js
export interface AVAFModel {
  bankingDetails: BankingDetails;
  digitalAcquisitionsConsent: DigitalAcquisitionsConsent;
  employmentDetails: EmploymentDetails;
  financeDetails: FinanceDetails;
  incomeAndExpenseDetails: IncomeAndExpenseDetails;
  personalAddressDetails: PersonalAddressDetails;
  personalDetails: PersonalDetails;
  vehicleAssetDetails: VehicleAssetDetails;
  preQualifiedCustomer: boolean | true;
}

prepareAvafSubmitData() {
  const avafBcmsRequestObj: AVAFModel = {
    bankingDetails: bankingDetailsVoModel,
    digitalAcquisitionsConsent: digitalAcquisitionsConsentVoModel,
    employmentDetails: employmentDetailsVoModel,
    financeDetails: financeDetailsVoModel,
    incomeAndExpenseDetails: incomeAndExpenseDetailsVoModel,
    personalAddressDetails: personalAddressDetailsVoModel,
    personalDetails: personalDetailsVoModel,
    vehicleAssetDetails: vehicleAssetDetailsVoModel,
    preQualifiedCustomer: this.getPrequalifiedStatus
  };

  return avafBcmsRequestObj;
}
```

Comment: Instead, `this.avafBcmsVo = this.prepareAvafSubmitData();`? This will match the data type. I believe that you are trying to add an object into an object? If yes, you should look for assign a value in an object's key. Don't manually build the JSON string, it is a high chance that you will end up with an invalid JSON due to the syntax error.

Comment: @YongShun yes I am trying to send `avafBcmsRequestObj` inside of `avafVO`

eg `{"avafVO": {avafBcmsRequestObj}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should declare another object variable instead of reusing `this.avafBcmsVo` which leads to an unmatched type.
2. Don't build JSON string manually. This will highly chance to lead to an invalid JSON due to syntax error. Instead, converting an object to JSON string via [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).

```js
submitAvafDetails(): Observable<any> {
  let avafBcmsVo: any = {
    avafVO: this.prepareAvafSubmitData()
  };

  return this.httpService.processData('POST', CONSTANTS.API_URL + 'testService.exp', JSON.stringify(avafBcmsVo));
}
```